# Two images overlays?

Tags: jquery, css, image, overlay

I would like to use two image overlays that layer on top of an image using jQuery.

The first overlay is always active, giving the image a slightly darker shade.
The second (darker overlay) is activated on mouseover to further darken.

Effectively there are 3 images: the image itself, and two overlay images.

The image must be coded as such: `<img src="image.jpg" />` and cannot be a background image as it is a responsive layout.

I am currently using the following jQuery for the mouseover overlay, but I need an 'always active' overlay as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.fade').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.tile-overlay').fadeIn(300);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.tile-overlay').fadeOut(250);
        }
    );

});

</script>
```

Comment: _I hope this is enough information._ ... Yes, this could be, but it would be better an unclearer question with some effort shown in it. We're not working for you, we are here to help you on what you have already tried.

Comment: Absolutely. I am currently using the following code for the mouseover overlay: 

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('.fade').hover(
  function(){
   $(this).find('.tile-overlay').fadeIn(300);
  },
  function(){
   $(this).find('.tile-overlay').fadeOut(250);
  }
 );
 
});

</script> but I need an 'always active' overlay as well, which I am stuck with. Any help would be brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: You can do this in just css without any additional images. Just use a semi-transparent black `div` on top of your image and change the transparency. Or a black background and change the opacity of the image...

Comment: CSS here is a way better solution, you don't need three images ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an overlay you can go for a CSS-only solution as it will work on almost any browser.

Here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pp7x5oL2/

You basically provide a basic styling and use CSS `>` to make the caption display too:

```
.element {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.element img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.caption-bg {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-top: -40px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
}

.caption {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.element:hover > .caption-bg {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.element:hover > .caption {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<div class="element">
    <img src="http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg" alt=" ">
        <div class="caption-bg"></div>
        <div class="caption">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

For this particular case I personally prefer to use `opacity` so I can add a transition for the caption too, and finally, to have it display in older browsers. You might aswell use `filter: alpha(opacity=XX)` to add some IE compatibility too.